# 404 Error not found on deploying app on VERCEL and NETLIFY

Tags: reactjs, netlify, vercel

Deployment successful on Netlify or even on Vercel but when I try to refresh
the page that I am in.. it gives ..

404 error[[VERCEL AND NETLIFY ERRORS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D1DJ1.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VgZW5.png)

I tried the solutions that they're offering but none of them works

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.